# Disable just one Javascript feature when in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loader screen which is just simply a white screen at this point. It all works fine on desktop but when on mobile view the whole hero header either disappears or shrinks entirely.

***NOT DESIRED***
[image: With Code]

***DESIRED***
[image]

I'm looking for a line of code that might just disable just the javascript on this page when in mobile view. I don't want to disable javascript all together as I have a separate js file which will be needed.

I believe it is occuring due to one element in particular:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
```

Here is the full code anyhow.

```
<style>
/* Center the loader */
.animate-bottom {
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom {
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}


</style>

</head>
<body onload="myFunction()" >

<div id="loader"></div>

<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
```

//CONTENT OF THE PAGE

```
    </div>
<script>
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 800);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: firstly check where your page is opened i.e to detect web or mobile device by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser using the link then disable your desired css

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out:

I changed this:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
```

to this:

```
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "initial";
```